# cant import component react native

Tags: android, react-native

So I'm new to react native and I am following this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUdy4PHIbww), and I can't seem to be able to import the 'Splash' component.

This is the error message I get

Error Message
[image]

And this is the code I have written

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import Splash from './splash';


export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (

      <Splash/>
    );
  }
}
```

And the component I want to import

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
       return(
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <View style={styles.titleWrapper}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Hello World!</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Powered by React 
Native</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

}

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    title: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 35,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

    subtitle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: '200',
        paddingBottom: 20

    },

    titleWrapper: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions you can do.  
1) Have you tried re-running your emulator. Sometimes you just need to rerun the emulator again as it does not pick up your files during first run. 
2) `import Spalsh  from './Splash` you need to capitalize your `Splash` 
3) Check your file path to splash. Its most likely incorrect.

Comment: Yeah that was it, I needed to capitalize `Splash` and fix a typo with `StyleSheet`